# JMS serializer serialize custom object and deserialize

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I'm most probably confused with visitors mechanism in JMS.
But I want achieve this:

serialize class to json and back with adding custom property **class** which indicates to what class deserialization should be made.

```
public static function getSubscribingMethods()
    {
        return [
            [
                'direction' => GraphNavigator::DIRECTION_SERIALIZATION,
                'format' => 'json',
                'type' => MyDTO::class,
                'method' => 'serializeMetadataDTO',
            ],
            [
                'direction' => GraphNavigator::DIRECTION_DESERIALIZATION,
                'format' => 'json',
                'type' => MyDTO::class,
                'method' => 'serializeMetadataDTO',
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function serializeMetadataDTO(
        JsonSerializationVisitor $visitor,
        MyDTO $dto,
        array $type,
        SerializationContext $context
    )
    {
        $visitor->visitArray([
            '__class__' => get_class($dto),
            'data' => $dto,
        ], $type, $context);
    }

    public function deserializeMetadataDTO(
        JsonDeserializationVisitor $visitor,
        ?array $data,
        array $type,
        SerializationContext $context
    )
    {
        if (null === $data) {
            return null;
        }

        $typeParser = new TypeParser();
        $dtoInstance = new $data['__class__'];

        $metadata = $context->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataForClass($data['__class__']);
        $visitor->startVisitingObject($metadata, $dtoInstance, $typeParser->parse($data['__class__']), $context);


        foreach ($data['data'] as $key => $value) {
            $visitor->visitProperty($metadata->propertyMetadata[$key], $value, $context);
        }

        return $visitor->endVisitingObject($metadata, $dtoInstance, $type, $context);
    }
```

1. Problem is when I do serialize, only `__class__` is serializer, `data` is not even part of array.
2. I should be able to deserialize `{"__class__":"MyBundle\\MyDTO","data":{"prop1":["x","xx"],"prop2":"x"}}`

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem. Part of my object was ignore by JMS Serializer when I do :

```
$serializer->deserialize($data, MyClass::class, 'json')
```

I understand that the problem is the getters and the setters of my camelCase object properties.

I fixed my problem with encoding my JSON data with JMS Serializer (initially with a sample `json_encode`), it convert all camelCase in snake_case. I don't know if this information can help you.

Anyway, if you have the same problem, this link can help you: https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations.
You can defined your own getter and setter in @Accessor annotation.